# Django APIRequestFactory converting CamelCase JSON keys and values to underscore_formatting

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

This generates a request and passes it to my view

```
factory = APIRequestFactory()
body = {'satellite': 'sat', 'groundStation': 'groundA'}
request = factory.post('/accesses', body)
response = view(request)
```

When the view function receives the request, `request.data` contains `{'satellite': 'sat', 'ground_station': 'ground_a'}`

The keys and there values have been reformatted. I'm trying to keep app this consistent with an API some other services are familiar with. How do I turn off this reformatting?

Comment: using any custom parser?

Comment: try `request = factory.post('/accesses', body, format='json')`

Comment: No luck @JerinPeterGeorge

Comment: Can you show the behaviour (screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

I was in fact setting a custom parser under one of my settings files. I changed it from CamelCaseParser to JSONParser and that seemed to work. I also changed my renderer.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/